# Why would one call stat64 explicitly?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, gdb

Env: Ubuntu 18.04, Linux Kernel 5.3

I'm debugging some binary with `gdb`. Here is what I found when catching `stat` system call:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f2d8ecae775 in __GI___xstat (vers=vers@entry=1, name=name@entry=0x7f2d882d7d60 "/etc/app/cfg", buf=buf@entry=0x7f2d8f3a14f0) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/wordsize-64/xstat.c:35
#1  0x00007f2d592294e4 in stat64 (__statbuf=0x7f2d8f3a14f0, __path=0x7f2d882d7d60 "/etc/app/cfg") at /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/stat.h:500
#2  0x00007f2d6fac1990 in ?? ()
#3  0x00007f2d8f3a15c8 in ?? ()
#4  0x00007f2d8f3a1620 in ?? ()
#5  0x00007f2d6fabbcb3 in ?? ()
#6  0x00000007170a2ae8 in ?? ()
#7  0x00007f2d8f3a15d0 in ?? ()
#8  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

The line `#1  0x00007f2d592294e4 in stat64 (__statbuf=0x7f2d8f3a14f0, __path=0x7f2d882d7d60 "/etc/app/cfg") at /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/stat.h:500` got me confused.

I don't have an idea about **why one would use `stat64` explicitly**. First of all it requires `_GNU_SOURCE` to be defined. Secondly to my knowledge glibc's `stat` already handle all the kernel-specific `32`/`64`-bit difference staff.

And besides, both the `stat` and `stat64` use the same `stat` system call on my kernel.

Comment: On my Ubuntu 19.10 the file `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/stat.h` contains a line `#  define stat stat64`. I didn't analyze under which conditions (#ifdef) this will be used. Maybe the source code actually contains `stat` and does not directly use `stat64`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely explanation is the program did a `#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64` before including any system headers. This causes   calls to plain `stat` to be remapped to `stat64`, `open` to `open64`, etc. Nowadays all applications should do this.

However, there is a reason to use `stat64` etc directly. In a library whose public interfaces logically should involve `off_t` or any of the other types that are changed by defining `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS`, you *can’t* use that define or any of those types in your interface headers because then your own ABI will depend on the setting of that macro, which is controlled by the library user, not you. Instead you have to define `_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE` and use the explicitly sized types (`off64_t`, etc.) and functions (`stat64`, etc.) in your interface headers. In principle, .c and .h files that aren't exposed to external macro defines can still use `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS` and the ordinary functions, but in practice it’s easier to enforce a style rule that *all* of the library’s code must use only the explicitly sized types and functions.